# having difficulty with responsive web design

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I would like the image to be a larger size on the computer, but to fit smaller devices. But when I try to have a larger image size for the computer, it also increase the size on the phone, and it shrinks and pushes my navigation (which is supposed to be in the middle) to the left. (my navigation is meant to be on the left hand side on the computer, but in the middle just horizontally on the smaller devices) How can I set different image sizes for different devices? I tried @media but it doesn't seem to be working. I'm a beginner, so could anyone see what it is that i'm doing wrong?

Areas where i experience the issue are on .typecontainer, .type, .type1

Link to Screenshots: http://imgur.com/bM5xdWR,P9eUx4v,mq3gpP1#0

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Example</title>
    <link rel=”stylesheet” type=”text/css” href=”style.css” />
    <meta name=”viewport” content=”width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0”>
</head>

<body>

<div id=”topNav”>
<nav class=”navigation” role=”navigation”>
<ul>
    <li class=”Work”>
        <a href=”Work.html”>Work</a>
    </li>
    <li class=”About”>
        <a href=”About.html”>About</a>
    </li>
    <li class=”Contact”>
        <a href=”Contact.html”>Contact</a>
    </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class=”typecontainer”>
    <img class=”type” src=”image.jpg”>
    <img class=”type1” src=”type1.jpg”>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#topNav{
    display:block;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

ul{
    padding:0;
}

ul li
{
    list-style-type: none!important;
    font-family: 'PT Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 6%;
    padding: 0 5px;
    font-size:25px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 100;
    line-height: 1%;
    float:left;
    margin-left: 18px;
    letter-spacing: -1px;


/* iphone */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) {
    .iphonecontainer .iphone .typecontainer .type .type1
    { max-width: 100%; }
}

/* ipad */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width :  1024px) {
    .iphonecontainer .iphone .typecontainer .type .type1
    { max-width: 100%; }
}

/* iphone */
@media (max-width : 480px) and (min-width : 320px) {
    #topNav{
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 320px;
    }
    ul{
        padding:15px;
    }
}

/* ipad */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
    #topNav{
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 320px;
    }
    ul{
        padding:15px;
    }
}

/* iphone */
@media (max-width : 480px) and (min-width : 320px) {
    #work_links{
        margin: 8%;
        width: 320px;
    }
}

.typecontainer
{
width:100%;
float:left;
margin-top:6.5%;
}

.type {
 display:block;
 max-width: 500px;
 margin: 0px auto;
 padding: 0;
 }

 .type1 {
 display:block;
 max-width: 500px;
 margin: 0px auto;
 padding: 0;
 }
```

Comment: Well for starters you can't have HTML elements outside of the body tag.

Comment: Can you make a snippet and remember to use pictures that we can see also, so that the issue is reproducible. Also, please indent the code properly to make it more readable.

Comment: Did you try and use bootstrap? It will save you a whole headache of problems. Especially cross browser issues.

Comment: Okay I will move them inside the body tag. I have not tried bootstrap, actually it's the first time i hear of it. And okay I will post a link with screenshots

Comment: y don't u use images as a background in css. They won't disturb the neighbor elements in that case.

Comment: I fixed the indentation. Working on linking the screenshots now

Comment: Are setting them as background in css how they are usually done on websites? If so could you give me an example of how I would write that?

Comment: Here is the link to the screenshots http://imgur.com/bM5xdWR,P9eUx4v,mq3gpP1#0

Comment: In your CSS you have `.iphonecontainer .iphone`, but that's not in your example HTML. Can you update your HTML to reflect that? Without being able to test, try changing `max-width: 100%;` to `width:100%` in your `@media` queries.

Comment: the .iphonecontainer and .iphone are from a different html page, does that make a difference? Okay, I just tried changing it to width:100% in my media queries, but it made no difference

Comment: @ppinzon Yes, it makes a huge difference. This is what you have `.iphonecontainer .iphone .typecontainer .type .type1` in your CSS, this is your HTML structure: image with class of `type1` OR `type`. What your CSS is saying is target an image with the class `type1` that is in an element with the class `type`, that is in an element with the class `typecontainer`, that is in an element with the class `iphone`, that is in an element with the class `iphonecontainer`. The CSS you posted will never affect the HTML you posted.